Create a tutorial using an overlay react native app
I have an app and would like to add a tutorial.
This tutorial will mainly consist in displaying an overlay on the app with a text in the center of this overlay and dhow some elements of the app on top of the overlay
This is a basic code sample
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Dimensions, Text, View } from "react-native";
import { TouchableOpacity } from "react-native-web";

function App() {
  const [tutorialOverlay, setTutorialOverlay] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log({ tutorialOverlay });
  }, [tutorialOverlay]);

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, height: "100%" }}>
      {tutorialOverlay && (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{
            position: "absolute",
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            height: Dimensions.get("window").height,
            width: Dimensions.get("window").width,
            backgroundColor: "#000",
            zIndex: 10,
            opacity: 0.5,
          }}
          onPress={() => setTutorialOverlay(false)}
        >
          <Text style={{ color: "#fff" }}>Welcome to the tutorial</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )}
      <View style={{ backgroundColor: "blue", flex: 1 }}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={{ margin: 30, padding: 10, backgroundColor: "white" }}
          onPress={() => setTutorialOverlay(true)}
        >
          <Text>Activate tutorial</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
      <View
        style={{
          position: "absolute",
          left: 0,
          right: 0,
          bottom: 0,
          flexDirection: "row",
          backgroundColor: "green",
        }}
      >
        <Text
          style={{
            width: "25%",
            padding: 10,
            textAlign: "center",
            color: "red",
          }}
        >
          FooterMenu1
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{
            width: "25%",
            padding: 10,
            textAlign: "center",
            color: "red",
            zIndex: tutorialOverlay ? 1 : 20,
          }}
        >
          FooterMenu2
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{
            width: "25%",
            padding: 10,
            textAlign: "center",
            color: "red",
          }}
        >
          FooterMenu3
        </Text>
        <Text
          style={{
            width: "25%",
            padding: 10,
            textAlign: "center",
            color: "red",
          }}
        >
          FooterMenu4
        </Text>
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;

Testable code there https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/tutorial-4lg357
Now the harder part will be to display for example the FooterMenu2 on top of the tutorial overlay, I tried with a zIndex but it could not work as his parent is under the overlay.

Have you considered using an external library such as Driver.js? Or do you want to create it yourself?

Thanks @EdoardoCamara but the lib does not looks compatible with react-native

There is react-native-copilot for React Native

hey what you can do here is:

give the footer menu a fixed height
make the tutorial modal height = (SCREEN_HEIGHT - FOOTER_MENU_HEIGHT)
align the tutorial modal to top of screen

this way the footer menu will always show even when the modal is open

Thanks but i only a butin of the footer not all the footer

you can pass the prop tutorialOverlay  to the footer component and when its open you hide the other buttons
